# React Native setState Maximum Update Depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am building a React Native Screen in which some of the contents opacity depends on the current scroll state:

```
state = {
    scroll: new Animated.Value(0)
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { scroll } = this.state
    scroll.addListener(({ value }) => (this._value = value))
}

renderForeground = () => {
    const { scroll } = this.state
    const titleOpacity = scroll.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 106, 154],
        outputRange: [1, 1, 0],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    return (
        <View style={styles.foreground}>
            <Animated.View style={{ opacity: titleOpacity }}>
                <Text style={styles.message}>Do you have time to play?</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}

render() {
    const { scroll } = this.state

    return (
        <StickyParallaxHeader
            foreground={this.renderForeground()}
            scrollEvent={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scroll } } }])} />
    )
}
```

Now I am trying to set the same opacity (titleOpacity calculated in the renderForeground() function) to my Navigation Header Title. My idea was to convert the opacity value to a hex value and set the headerTintColor like this:

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({headerTintColor: "#ffffff" + alpha_value})
```

To make this alpha_value synchronize with the titleOpacity I wanted to use setState in the renderForeground() function:

```
const { scroll } = this.state
const titleOpacity = scroll.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 106, 154],
  outputRange: [1, 1, 0],
  extrapolate: 'clamp'
})

this.setState({headerOpacity: titleOpacity})
```

However the plan already fails here, as I am getting the following error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops

Is there another way to synchronize the scroll state and the header title color?

Comment: Setting state causes a re-render, so if rendering the component causes a setState, you'll end up with an infinite loop. Just don't use state for the opacity; calculate it then use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be calling setState inside render(), as that triggers a rerender of the component, triggering setState(), triggering a rerender, etc. This is the reason for the error you are getting.

If the header is in the same component, as it seems to be since you are using `setState`, then you can pass the interpolated value from your render method to both components:

```
render() {
    const { scroll } = this.state

    const titleOpacity = scroll.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 106, 154],
        outputRange: [1, 1, 0],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    return (
      <>
        <Header titleOpacity={titleOpacity} />
        <StickyParallaxHeader
            foreground={this.renderForeground(titleOpacity)}
            scrollEvent={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scroll } } }])} />
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! The problem is, that I do not have a Header-Component, I am using the React Navigation Header, which I can (as far as I know) only modify using "this.props.navigation.setOptions()". So the question is, where/how am I calling this function?